# CloudKit CKError domain code=1

Tags: icloud, cloudkit

If I run application with 3G internet access - every CloudKit query failed with error

> CKError 0x1559b9a0: "Internal Error" (1/4000); "Couldn't renew our
>   secure session"

With Wi-Fi everything is great. Can anybody solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer. If the user has the Settings > iCloud > Documents & Data > User Cellular Data option turned off (this is the default for iOS8), then this is the error you will get when not on Wi-Fi.